# Phonegap not calling device ready function

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am unable to get the device ready function to work within phonegap i.e. xcode simulator. The html is as follow: `

```
    <title>Boilerplate</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" class="logo">
            <img class="logo" src="img/premium-logo.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

            <h1>Apache Cordova Test Zone</h1>
            <div class="test-zone" id="test-zone">

            </div>

        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">

            <h4>Footer of main page</h4>

        </div>

    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery-Mobile-1.3.1-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(init());
    </script>
</body>
```

the Javascript file index.js:

```
 function init() {
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 }

 function onDeviceReady() {
   alert('It works!');
 }
```

If i comment out the line inside the init function and replace it simply with onDeviceReady(); I can get the alert to work on chrome.

Why won't it work in the simulator with the code above.
Thank you

Comment: I'd try to register `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` outside `$(document).ready()`. Besides that `$(document).ready()` takes `function` as argument, eg. `$(document).ready(init);`

Comment: I tried calling document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); and i have the init function being called on device ready. Still can't see where this is not working

Comment: Well then, what's in logs? I have no chance of working with PhoneGap for iOS but with Adnroid it didn't fired few time due to broken JS and I could see it in debug logs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

onDeviceReady event only works when testing your phonegap application from the device emulator, not in chrome.

Here is the best way I have found to do the two frameworks (phonegap and jQuery Mobile) to work together.

In my index.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/LABjs/LAB.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jQuery/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
```

Please notice I use the LABjs Library to load JS scripts (cordova.js is being to be loaded only if we detect that we are in a device), you can find it in google for LABjs library.

In my "js/index.js"

```
 var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
 var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
 var resourcesReady = false;


 var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);

        //load scripts
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
            $LAB.script("cordova.js").wait(
                function(){
                    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
                    console.log('We are on Device');
                }
            );
        }else
        {
            console.log('We are on Browser');
            var _this = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
                _this.onDeviceReady(); 
            }, 1);
        }

        console.log('app.initialize() Called');
        $.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(this.doWhenBothFrameworksReady);
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        console.log("onDeviceReady");
        deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
    },

    doWhenBothFrameworksReady: function()
    {
        console.log("doWhenBothFrameworksReady");
        resourcesReady = true;
    }
};

$(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true;
    console.log('MobileInit');
    jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
 });



function PageShowFunction(e)
{
    // we are sure that both frameworks are ready here
}

function CallPageEvent(funcToCall,e)
{
    if(resourcesReady)
    {
        return funcToCall(e);
    }else
    {
        setTimeout(function() {
            CallPageEvent(funcToCall,e);
        }, 200);
    }
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("document ready");
    // ALL the jQuery Mobile page events on pages must be attached here otherwise it will be too late 
    // example:
    // I use the CallPageEvent beacause this event could be called before the device ready
    /* 
     $("#page").on("pageshow", function(e) {
                CallPageEvent(PageShowFunction,e);
            }
     */



});

app.initialize();
```

Comment: Yes i know that i was just saying i used chrome to check that the function was being called which it is.But it still does not work on IOS simulator. it loads the app but will not show the alert message i have in the onDeviceReady function

Comment: The problem then is that the onDeviceReady function has already been fired when you set the event in the "ready" event of the document. Phoneap and jquery mobil are having this issue when working togheter, I will post a complete way of working with two frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort

Comment: You are welcome, if you doit in this way, your html will work in both browser (PC) and devices.

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

inside your index.html file, worked for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     init(); 
</script>
```

INSTEAD OF

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ init(); });
 </script>`
```