# deviceready event not firing in Cordova 3.2.0

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using Cordova **3.2.0**-0.3.0 and NetBeans **7.4** to develop a Cordova application. Although it works properly in the Mobile's Chrome browser, it does not seem to work properly neither in my phone (Android 4.1.2) nor in the emulator (Android 4.3, API level 18).
The problem seems to be that the `deviceready` event is never fired.

This is the code:

```
app.onReady = function(callback) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // are we running in native app or in browser?
        window.isphone = false;
        if (document.URL.indexOf("http://") === -1
                && document.URL.indexOf("https://") === -1) {
            window.isphone = true;
        }

        if (window.isphone) {
            alert("isPhone");
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", callback, false);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
};

app.onReady(function(){ alert("test"); });
```

"test" it is never shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808586/phonegap-not-calling-device-ready-function

Comment: Stupid question: are you sure that the `cordova-x.js` is included correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As ignitor guessed, I forgot to include the `cordova.js`.
Though I must say, in my defense (:P), that it is weird to include a script like if it was on your root when it is not there (at least when testing in a browser).

Comment: For testing in the browser, you may consider using [Phonegap-Desktop](https://github.com/jxp/phonegap-desktop) which simulates some of the Cordova API in the browser.

Comment: I created a cordova project using the CLI tools and somehow assumed the dependency would be injected into the root html automatically. Obviously it wasn't so there was my mistake as well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be that the `deviceready`event is triggered **before** the DOM is ready, i.e. before the `$(document).ready()` callback is executed.

You should try to bind to `deviceready` independently of `$(document).ready()`.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17809399/490560) for an example of how to do that.

Comment: That isn't supposed to be the case. The Cordova docs say: "The deviceready event behaves somewhat differently from others. Any event handler registered after the deviceready event fires has its callback function called immediately." Therefore, if the deviceready event is attached after it initially fires, then it should return immediately. (I'm suddenly running into the same problem as the author, but this worked for me in the past.)

Comment: Oh. That sentence came in in version 2.2.0. So the question is whether this features was introduced in 2.2.0 or wasn't just documented before 2.2.0. On the other hand, the op uses 3.2.0 so it doesn't matter after all. :-/