# DeviceReady not firing on PhoneGap Build (Bd)

Tags: cordova

My config.xml is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap     = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id            = "com.example.test"
    versionCode   = "10" 
    version       = "1.0.0">

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
</widget>
```

I reference both the device, and network information, however, with my JavaScript (wrapped within  within head in index.html):

```
<script src='phonegap.js'></script>
<script>
    alert("Loaded.");
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
        alert("Fired.");
        alert(device.uuid);
    });
</script>
```

I get a popup `Loaded.` as expected, but I don't get `Fired.` or the device's UUID either.

I have tried adding separately the phonegap/cordova libraries respectively (one at a time):

```html
<script src='phonegap.js'></script>
```

```html
<script src='cordova.js'></script>
```

They cause the application to show `Error initializing Cordova: Class not found"`.

Snap of plugins loaded into the online build:

[image]

I'm running Android 4.0.3. I've also tried accessing device but it just says device in undefined.
I have disabled hydration as well.
What should I try next? (I'd like to get device.* and deviceready event to work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you :

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("deviceready", OnDeviceReady, false);

function OnDeviceReady()    {
alert("Device is ready");
}
</script>
```

Also refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808586/phonegap-not-calling-device-ready-function)

Comment: I have only added one of each per testing. (Ex. first with phonegap alone, then cordova alone, then with nothing) I also have the above script in index.html within the head tag.

Comment: ok... Can you also please check whether you are calling Deviceready event after placing phonegap.js script?

Comment: Sweet it works now. The issue was because I was placing a loading a deferred script and that resulted the addEventListener to be fired after. It was also due to hydration not refreshing the javascript libraries being loaded in.

Comment: However, it still fails whenever I activate Hydration. It seems to not want to load the library, and if I do remove it, it doesn't generate the class error, but doesn't fire the event either. I plan on using hydration for development (of course), and when I do finish, I rest assured that after disabling hydration, my script will be able to access the appropriate API. If there is any followup for allowing device.* with conjunction of Hydration, I'm all ears.